# I can be deep, I can be paw, what am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

```
A riddle to divine my name and nature, clues I have in store,

I can be deep, I can be paw, these clues I give, do you need more?

My name they use when things go wrong, I don't know who first said it,

A disappearing act is a neat trick should I take credit?

Horses or a bright red bird may make some think of me,

My name they use when things go wrong, does that seem fair to thee?

Half the world is mine and yet I do not need a crown,

So why do people seem to think that I am lower down?
```

What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> South

fits some of the clues

> "deep south",  "southpaw",

"lower down"

> on maps and globes

something that fails

> has "gone south",

half the world

> is the southern hemisphere

But the birds

> of the south are black and white: penguins

and horses must be relevant so some, but not to me.

**Full Answer**

I can be deep, I can be paw, these clues I give, do you need more?

> deep south, south paw

My name they use when things go wrong, I don't know who first said it,

> Things are going (or have gone) south

A disappearing act is a neat trick should I take credit?

> Going south is another way of saying vanishing or disappearing

Horses or a bright red bird may make some think of me,

> In symbolism, a horse often represents the direction of south, or a vermilion bird in some eastern cultures

Half the world is mine and yet I do not need a crown,

> The southern hemisphere

So why do people seem to think that I am lower down?

> Some people just don't get the relativity.

Comment: Don't you just hate it when someone solves a puzzle in a fraction of the time it takes to come up with it?  Well done.  +1

Comment: Brilliant and great explanation!

Comment: @BrentHackers The solve time may be increased if you try to cloak some of the compound words.  "I can be deep, I can be paw..." Well, "paw" isn't an adjective, so it forms an incorrect sentence structure, which makes it pretty clear that we're probably looking for something that goes with "paw" as-is. Therefore, we are probably also looking for something that goes with "deep" as-is. Combine the two and you can probably guess without any of the other lines.